# VPN connection break inbound traffic

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing

I have a Server with (66.66.66.66)(not the real IP of course), and my home network has a public IP(202.202.122.123) too.

After I connect to Server from Router(172.22.34.1) using VPN(Technically OpenVPN, that shouldn't matter) for proxy,

Then I have a main route table like this:

`202.202.122.1 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link 
172.22.34.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.22.34.1
10.12.12.0/24 dev tap11  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.12.2
default via 202.202.122.1 dev ppp0`

and a ov1 route table like this:

`172.22.34.0/24 dev br0  scope link 
66.66.66.66/32 via 202.202.122.1 dev ppp0
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.12.12.1 dev tap11 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.12.12.1 dev tap11`

and ip rule like this(I do this mean to control who can use VPN tunnel):

`0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from 172.22.34.101 lookup ov1
32765:  from 172.22.34.44 lookup ov1
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default`

The server with IP 66.66.66.66 can view the HTTPS web hosted on home (202.202.122.123:443 DNAT to 172.22.34.44:443), but **others** no(My phone, Online port check tool, etc.).

Then I tracked packages using tshark(wireshark CLI) on 172.22.34.44, there is no even inbound traffic when trying to view the web from my phone(using cellular network), but after I **ONLY need to** manually add phone's IP to ov1 route table like the server(`ip route add PHONEIP dev ppp0 table ov1`), then it works fine.

The thing which makes me confused is **as I know**, route table said "Destination" not "Source":

`Kernel IP routing table`
**Destination**`....Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
202.202.122.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
172.22.34.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
10.12.12.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap11
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         202.202.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0`

Which should only affect outbound traffic, I didn't expect that inbound traffic will disappear.

**Where's wrong?**

PS.1 When del 172.22.34.44 from ip rule to make it to use main route table it works fine too.

PS.2.1`ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev ppp0 table ov1` has no effect, which
PS.2.2`ip route add PHONEIP   dev ppp0 table ov1` has effect.(mentioned before)

PS.3 Any documents to recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: IP route is stateless, route table is for destination, `ip rule` can check and mark/connmark source.

Main question seems resolved by using `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0/rp_filter` to disable reverse path checking. The route table means destination indeed, not the source IP.

For who wondering what's happened, here's a quick explanation.

When an IP from 0.0.0.0/0(equals 0.0.0.0/1 + 128.0.0.0/1 on ov1 route table) via ppp0(eth0) tries to connect 202.202.122.123:443,
router will DNAT it,
then use main route because as which `ip rule` command shows(**from** ALL lookup main),
172.22.34.44(:443) responses,
but now router now will use ov1 table(**from** 172.22.34.44 lookup ov1),
tries to send this package out via tap11,
then if reverse path checking is ON on router,
this package will be dropped.

So the best solution to my problem is <del>to add a virtual interface 172.22.34.45 on 172.22.34.44, then DNAT to 172.22.34.45.</del> use fwmark and prioritize it over the 172.22.34.44 rule and DISABLE RP_FILTER OR ENABLE SRC_VALID_MARK.